# git over sshfs (with idmap): unable to append to '.git/logs/HEAD': Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, users, sshfs

#### Problem:

I have a git repository mounted via sshfs and cannot commit changes with the following error message:

```
fatal: cannot update the ref 'HEAD': unable to append to '.git/logs/HEAD': Permission denied
```

Note that I can

```bsh
cp -a .git/logs/HEAD .git/logs/HEAD.bu
printf foo > .git/logs/HEAD
mv .git/logs/HEAD.bu .git/logs/HEAD
```

without a problem, but

```bsh
printf foo >> .git/logs/HEAD
```

gives me the 'Permission denied' as well.

#### Question:

What do I need to change about my configuration to be able to commit from my local machine to the remote repository?

#### What I tried:

Given the above symptoms, I assume the issue lies with appending to a file.
I found [Git repository on SSHFS: unable to append to '.git/logs/HEAD': Invalid argument](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/388722/65290) which refers to https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/issues/82 suggesting the issue (note the slighty differerent error message) could be solved by mounting the remote file system with `writeback_cache=no`. The latter source quotes the `man` page referencing the following caveat/workaround:

> ```
> CAVEATS / WORKAROUNDS
> [...]
>    O_APPEND
>        When  writeback  caching is enabled, SSHFS cannot reliably support the O_APPEND open
>        flag and thus signals an error on open.  To enable support for  unreliable  O_APPEND
>        (which  may  overwrite  data if the file changes on the server at a bad time), mount
>        the file system with -o unreliable_append.
> ```

However, this section is not in my man page:

```bsh
sshfs -V
```

```
SSHFS version 3.7.0
FUSE library version 3.9.1
using FUSE kernel interface version 7.31
fusermount3 version: 3.9.1
```

I found that the writeback-cache feature that I tried to disable, [was actually removed](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/commit/d193b19a8f60e8830f0aa5696d2bf3d4fd8d7930) (after being [disabled](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/commit/1e6e067fdf91d54bcf72071b00315969cf1ea9d7) and [re-enabled](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/commit/d141ea44c1d901c27f61865808e8c5f9801b2606) [more than once](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/commit/f8df458f239de38d29be3161f46cd7fba74bdacf) before).
So I guess I *should* be good but clearly there (still) is a problem.

A further complication that I should probably mention, is that my user name and ID on the remote system do not match the local one, so I need to used the `idmap` feature.

Here is the corresponding `fstab` entry:

```
<remote-user>@<remote-machine>: /mnt/ssh/<remote-machine>  sshfs  _netdev,user,idmap=user,allow_other  0 0
```

Also, my `/etc/fuse.conf` contains

```
user_allow_other
```

#### Background:

To avoid answer just telling me not to do this:

- I know how git works.
- I know I can clone the repository locally, commit there, and push to the remote one over ssh.

Why I don't do it? - Because I track code that can only be tested on the remote machine and I do want to test it before committing.
So to some extent this is 'just' a convenience issue to avoid having to:

1. Edit code on the local copy.
2. Commit the changes to the local copy.
3. Push to the remote copy.
4. SSH to the remote machine (or switch terminals).
5. Test the code on the remote machine.
6. Checkout another branch (to allow force-pushing).
7. End the SSH sessions (or switch [back] terminals).
8. Edit the code.
9. Amend the previous commit on the local copy.
10. Force-push to the remote copy.
11. SSH to the remote machine (or switch terminals).
12. Checkout the force-pushed branch.
13. Repeat steps 5 - 11 (seven steps!) until I'm happy.

Instead, I want to:

1. SSH to the remote machine (or switch terminals).
2. Edit code on the remote copy from the remote machine.
3. Test the code on the remote machine.
4. Edit code on the remote copy from the remote machine.
5. Repeat steps 3 - 4 (two steps!) until I'm happy.
6. End the SSH sessions (or switch [back] terminals).
7. Commit the changes to the remote copy from the local machine.

Why don't I simply commit from the remote machine? - Because I want to sign my commits but can't entrust the remote machine with the private key.
So the best alternative I could come up with is:

1. SSH to the remote machine (or switch terminals).
2. Edit code on the remote copy from the remote machine.
3. Test the code on the remote machine.
4. Edit code on the remote copy from the remote machine.
5. Repeat steps 3 - 4 (two steps!) until I'm happy.
6. Commit the changes to the remote copy from the remote machine.
7. Checkout another branch (to allow force-pushing).
8. End the SSH sessions (or switch [back] terminals).
9. Pull from the remote copy.
10. Amend (sign) the previous commit on the local copy.
11. Force-push to the remote copy.
12. SSH to the remote machine (or switch terminals).
13. Checkout the force-pushed branch.

So on the one hand, I'd like to get rid of these extra steps (things get more complicated when adding feature branches as those need to be properly checked out on both copies and configured for proper tracking), on the other I want to understand why it doesn't 'just work'(tm).

---

**Update:**

Following up on [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/593649/git-over-sshfs-with-idmap-unable-to-append-to-git-logs-head-permission-de?noredirect=1#comment1110371_593649) by [@tukan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/258307/tukan), I reproduced the error with debug output:

1. Mount remote with debug output:

```bsh
 mount -o sshfs_debug MOUNTPOINT
```

```
SSHFS version 3.7.0
executing <ssh> <-x> <-a> <-oClearAllForwardings=yes> <-2> <USER@SERVER> <-s> <sftp>
USER@SERVER's password:
Server version: 3
Extension: versions <2,3,4,5,6>
Extension: fsync@openssh.com <1>
Extension: posix-rename@openssh.com <1>
Extension: statvfs@openssh.com <2>
Extension: fstatvfs@openssh.com <2>
Extension: hardlink@openssh.com <1>
remote_uid = 0
```

2. In a different terminal, access the mounted share:

```bsh
cd MOUNTPOINT/DIR_WITH_WRITE_PERMISSIONS
```

```
[00002] LSTAT
  [00002]          ATTRS       45bytes (188ms)
```

3. Verify regular writing works:

```bsh
echo foo > foobar
```

```
[00003] LSTAT
  [00003]         STATUS       38bytes (46ms)
[00004] LSTAT
  [00004]         STATUS       38bytes (32ms)
[00005] LSTAT
  [00005]          ATTRS       45bytes (242ms)
[00006] OPENDIR
  [00006]         HANDLE       29bytes (31ms)
[00007] READDIR
[00008] READDIR
  [00007]           NAME      668bytes (58ms)
[00009] READDIR
[00010] READDIR
  [00008]           NAME      483bytes (65ms)
[00011] READDIR
[00012] READDIR
  [00009]         STATUS       37bytes (27ms)
  [00010]         STATUS       37bytes (27ms)
[00013] CLOSE
[00014] LSTAT
  [00011]         STATUS       37bytes (27ms)
  [00012]         STATUS       37bytes (27ms)
  [00013]         STATUS       28bytes (26ms)
  [00014]         STATUS       38bytes (31ms)
[00015] OPEN
[00016] LSTAT
  [00015]         HANDLE       29bytes (153ms)
  [00016]          ATTRS       45bytes (158ms)
[00017] FSTAT
  [00017]          ATTRS       45bytes (29ms)
[00018] WRITE
  [00018]         STATUS       28bytes (28ms)
[00019] CLOSE
  [00019]         STATUS       28bytes (28ms)
```

4. Trigger error by attempting to append:

```bsh
echo bar >> foobar
```

```
[00020] LSTAT
  [00020]         STATUS       38bytes (74ms)
[00021] LSTAT
  [00021]         STATUS       38bytes (57ms)
[00022] LSTAT
  [00022]          ATTRS       45bytes (52ms)
[00023] OPENDIR
  [00023]         HANDLE       29bytes (53ms)
[00024] READDIR
[00025] READDIR
  [00024]           NAME      668bytes (68ms)
[00026] READDIR
[00027] READDIR
  [00025]           NAME      597bytes (77ms)
[00028] READDIR
[00029] READDIR
  [00026]         STATUS       37bytes (47ms)
[00030] CLOSE
  [00027]         STATUS       37bytes (47ms)
[00031] OPEN
[00032] LSTAT
  [00028]         STATUS       37bytes (47ms)
  [00029]         STATUS       37bytes (47ms)
  [00030]         STATUS       28bytes (26ms)
  [00031]         STATUS       43bytes (28ms)
  [00032]          ATTRS       45bytes (29ms)
```

```
zsh: permission denied: foobar
```

Hope this helps to find the root cause of my problem.

---

Note: Based on [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/595076/65290) by [@Devidas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/145814/devidas) (and the lack of a solution even after a desparate attention-seeking bounty week), [I cross-posted this to the corresponding GitHub issue](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/issues/117#issuecomment-651560293).

Comment: Can you read the file? `cat .git/logs/HEAD`

Comment: @tukan: Of course! As I wrote, I can also write to it (be it via `mv`, as shown above, or using `nvim`),  As I wrote, `>` redirection works but `>>` fails. So I suspect this to be an issue with sshfs, not Git (thus no Git tag on this question). Git probably just tries to open that file in write-append mode causing the faulty permission error.

Comment: The problem is not writing, that works for you.  The problem, as you specified, is with using `>>` (append) is that you need to read the contents first or at least check where is the `EOF` and then you append the contents.  The question is what really happens with the git there (as you noted).  Could you show us your `sshfs` debug log (`-o sshfs_debug`)?

Comment: @tukan: Thx for following up. I updated the question to include a simpler reproduction (no Git) with `-o sshfs_debug` output.

Comment: You are welcome does the directory `MOUNTPOINT/DIR_WITH_WRITE_PERMISSIONS`  has also read permissions?  Could you show us the `ls -la`?  Who is the owner?

Comment: @tukan: Yes, I do. If I `cat foobar` after the new test, I get 'foo'. The whole directory belongs to my (remote) user. It is a git repository I cloned on that machine where I do not have sudo permissions. Otherwise, also the `cp` command from my initial post would have failed with 'permission' denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

such a big and detailed question.
Lets solve this step by step. Error is "Permission denied"

```
Linux error code
EACCES          13      /* Permission denied */
```

when I searched for `EACCES` in sshfs repo
I found only two instances in file `[sshfs.c][1]`

one is about file permission in local context. the one you demonstrated.

other is `SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED`
error from ssh permission denied.

From data I have I can say for almost certainty. that
As you have permission in local machine

Cases

```
printf foo >> .git/logs/HEAD
```

reason this gives permission denied and not

```
printf foo > .git/logs/HEAD
```

either you don't have permission on remote machine or
remote servers that don't support `O_APPEND` refer to [issue 117](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/issues/117)

you can verify it using strace.

this is why part.
How to solve depends on your reply. which case is it?

Do let me know so that I can help you further.

feel free to comment if you disagree.

Comment: Thx for the response. The remote machine actually is an SFTP server is this case. I could try another one were I have full interactive SSH access that mounts the same filesystem (though it is explicitily not intended for data transfer) just to make sure it is server-related. How would I use `strace` verify 'it' (what exactly)?

Comment: Note that I updated the question based on feedback by @tukan. Maybe this helps you to further help me. ;-)

Comment: I did award this question the bounty as it was the only attempt of at least trying to help me. Seems my best hope is to get a over two-year old enhancement issue worked on, included in a new release, and that getting stable enough to propagate to my distro's repositories...thx anyways for the pointer.

Comment: @mschilli strace utility helps tracing system calls. So you will see exactly which syscall is failing and with which error code. If you compare strace for both cases you will see the difference. Hence solving the mistry why you could write to that file and why you can't append.

Comment: I did not ask *'What does `strace` do and how would it help to better understand the issue?'* but *'**How** would I use it (in this particular case)?'*. ;-) But thank you anyways for your help. At least you pointed me to the correct bug and it appears there is no proper solution nor a better workaround. So I'm going to accept this answer (and +1 obviously) as it looks like this is the best answer I could hope for and you made the effort to help.